# Make JFrame Title Bar not count for pixels

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am making a game in Java as a way to teach me more about Java and Game Programming in general. But, I have one question. The Title Bar on my JFrame takes up 29 Y-pixels of the space. Therefore, I have less drawing room then I had planned. Is there a way to make it so the corner of the JFrame Canvas is the point (0,0) and not (0, 29)? Thanks

Comment: For high performance rendering, it might be better to look to [Full-Screen Exclusive Mode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/index.html).

Answer (score 7):

The answer is simple: don't draw in the JFrame's `paint(...)` method but rather in a JPanel's `paintComponent(...)` method, and then make the JPanel the JFrame's contentPane. This solution is well described in the [Swing Tutorials painting section](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html), and there are several reasons to do this including:

- You don't risk drawing over things that shouldn't be drawn over including borders and title bars.
- You get the advantage of Swing's default double buffering which can make a huge improvement if you do any animation.

Comment: If I want to paint directly to the panel (aka through use of `getGraphics()` instead of overriding `paint()`), how would I get this solution to work? I'm doing that since I'm manually doing the threading, and I'd like to paint on my own thread immediately.

Comment: @JakeKing You can't.  What you can do is generate a `BufferedImage` in your thread and paint to that and then ask the screen to render it from within it's `paintComponent` method.  Also, DON'T update ANY UI element from any thread other then Event Dispatching Thread

Comment: @MadProgrammer Alternate: *"What you can do is generate a BufferedImage in your thread and.."* ..display it in a label.  Call `label.repaint()` to update the GUI.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Nice, cheeky, but nice